# Ender 5 Printing Issues

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, creality-ender-5

I'm brand new to 3D printing. Just got me an Ender 5 Pro. After messing around for the last couple of days with bed leveling, I'm finally able to get consistent first level all thought I have to increase filament speed to 120 otherwise there are too many gaps in the base. Now I'm trying to work out issues printing [this Calibration cube](https://www.thingiverse.com/make:737567). 
My corners are being rounded too much and therefore size of cube differs. 20.02-20.08 mm when checking middle or when including corners goes to 20.50.

When I printed a full-sized model of an owl, it looks like it has stitching on the back. And random bumps all over.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bumps on the owl could also be your seam if it’s not overextrusion. I used to have that problem on a ton of my prints until I set the seam to sharpest corner or user defined. You can go to the Teaching Tech website to get some tips on how to fix some common problems or calibrate your printer. Good luck!